# Why does the ++ operator cause a stack overflow in my recursive method yet +1 does not?

Tags: java, recursion

So I just took a CS test at school tonight and I had to write a recursive method that found the max value in an array.

This is what I came up with:

```
public static int getMax(int[] a, int max, int index)
    {
        if(index == a.length)
        {
            return max;
        }
        if(a[index] > max)
        {
            max = a[index];
        }
        return getMax(a, max, index++);
    }
```

That's what I put on the paper I turned in, but lo and behold I get home and put it in my IDE to try it out and see if it works and I get a stack overflow. So I do some testing and finally change the second return to:

`return getMax(a, max, index+1);`

and no more stack overflow.

Why does the `++` operator break the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++` in suffix form increments *after* the variable is evaluated.  You're passing the current value of the index into your recursive call, then incrementing it locally back in the parent function.  In other words, you keep passing the same index value into deeper and deeper recursive calls until you run out of stack.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea. Hopefully my instructor will show mercy. xD

Comment: Once you understand the difference between prefix and postfix increment/decrement, they can be very powerful.  Until then, they can be hazardous to your health.

Comment: Well my understanding of it was that it was just shorthand for `var = var+1`. Although it still is, just local like you said.

Comment: @Habitat Consider `a = 1; b = a++;` vs `a = 1; b = ++a;`.  The value of `a` becomes 2 in both cases, but `b` gets assigned 1 in the first case and 2 in the second.  The first (suffix) version uses the value of `a` in the assignment, *then* increments, while the prefix form increments `a` first and then uses it in the assignment.

Comment: Nice I hadn't considered ++var as an actual thing. I appreciate the extra detail you've added to your answer. I should be all set now.